# Recent installation of Ubuntu 16.04 crashes continuosly

Tags: 16.04, crash

I have recently updated Ubuntu to 16.04 (32 bit) on our office machine.
Installation went fine, but system crashes frequently when we are browsing the net.

Following some suggestions on this forum, I looked at `/var/log/syslog` and I have found these errors:

```
Dec  3 11:42:31 scanninglab-Inspiron-545 org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1052]: ** (gvfsd:1125): WARNING **: dbus_mount_reply: Error from org.gtk.vfs.Mountable.mount(): Recupero dell'elenco delle condivisioni dal server non riuscito: Connessione rifiutata

Dec  3 11:42:31 scanninglab-Inspiron-545 org.gtk.vfs.Daemon[1052]: ** (process:2138): WARNING **: Couldn't create directory monitor on smb://x-gnome-default-workgroup/. Error: La posizione specificata non è montata

Dec  3 11:44:37 scanninglab-Inspiron-545 kernel: [  205.906000] perf: interrupt took too long (2536 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 78750

Dec  3 11:45:53 scanninglab-Inspiron-545 kernel: [  282.030943] perf: interrupt took too long (3238 > 3170), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 61750
```

Sorry for the Italian parts, but it basically complains about failed connection to a server and unmounted positions.

I do not have any idea on what I can do.
Could you please give me any help?

Best regards,
Antonio Iuliano

P.S. Previous version of Ubuntu on this machine was Ubuntu 10.04 and it worked fine.

> Processor is Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU E7400 @ 2.80GHz × 2
>   Graphic is NVA5

Comment: Update on the issue: I have discovered that system does not crash if I use Chromium instead of Firefox as an Internet Browser.